# Approval Process : What will happen if approver is inactive

Tags: approval-process

If Account object have approval process, if submitter submit the record for approval. It is assign to manager. What if manager is inactive/freeze?

Thanks in advance.?

Answer (score 4):

While submitting for approval to an `inactive` user you will get an error message.

`operation performed with inactive user`

For `freezed` accounts you will be able to submit for approval though.